# how to initialize swift enum instance dynamically

Tags: swift

we have

```
enum Foo: Int {
    case A
    case B
    case C
}

enum Bar: Int {
    case D
    case E
    case F
}
```

we can do

```
let i = 0;
let typeOfEnum = Foo.self;
let ins = typeOfEnum.init(rawValue: 1)
```

but how to write a generic function to initialize enum instance which raw value is Int(or others)

```
T newEnumInstance(theType : T.Type , rawValue: Int) {
    ???????
}
```

Comment: great thx, exactly what I need.